# Series of real numbers.

Tags: real-analysis

How to prove that the series $\sum a_{n}$ is convergent iff  $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=n}^\infty a_{k}=0 .$ Its sequence of partial sums $\langle S_{n}\rangle $ will converge to its sums. How can i use it or by some other idea to prove the above result?  I tried like this

Since $\langle S_{n}\rangle$ is convergent and so Cauchy sequence. For given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$  such that $$|S_{n}-S_{m}|<\varepsilon,\quad n\geq m\geq N$$ Which is same as $$\left|\sum_{m+1}^{n}a_{n}\right|<\varepsilon,\quad m\geq N $$
Am i right ? How to proceed to further. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all the thing you're trying to prove sounds fishy. Do you have a "special" definition for convergence and infinite series? The $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k$ would be well defined iff $\sum a_k$ is (that is the series converges).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, this may or may not help.

Suppose $l=\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_n$ (the series is convergent). Then $\sum^\infty_{n=k}a_n = l-\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}a_k=l-S_{n-1} $. So, $\mbox{lim}_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum^\infty_{n=k}a_n = l-\mbox{lim}_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_{n-1}=l-l=0$

That's one direction at least.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k$ is not well defined unless $\sum a_n$ converges, I think you're on the right track.

What you need to show is that $\sum_{m+1}^n a_k$ converges as $n\to\infty$, but that follows from $S_n-S_m$ converges. Now when you know it converges you know that $|\sum_{m+1}^\infty a_k| \le \epsilon$. That should hopefuly be enough to get you further.

After you have prooven the implication rightways you of course has to prove the reverse to, that is if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k$ converges, then $\sum a_k$ converges.